# How do you create a customer in Jira Service Desk using the JSD Cloud API?

Tags: python, rest, jira, jira-rest-api

Hi and thanks for taking the time to have a think about this one.

I am trying to create a customer in Jira Service Desk, JSD, Cloud.

- My account is a project admin
- My account is not a global admin
- When I create a new customer via the JSD user interface it is accepted
- When I create a new customer via the [JSD API](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/service-desk/rest/api-group-customer/#api-rest-servicedeskapi-customer-post) a 403 response is returned.

Here is the Python I have written to test this so far.

```
def create_customer(service_desk_id: int, display_name: str, email: str):
    # creates customer in specified JSD project.
    log.write("jsd.create_customer start")
    # POST customer
    from requests import post
    from json import dumps, loads
    url = f"{jsd_base_url}/servicedesk/{service_desk_id}/customer"

    payload = dumps({
        "displayName": display_name,
        "email": email
    })

    response = post(
        url=url,
        data=payload,
        headers=headers,
        auth=auth
    )
    log.write("jsd.create_customer end")

    return loads(response.text)
```

I have already tried asking on the [Atlassian forum](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Service-Desk-questions/Why-do-I-need-global-admin-permissions-to-add-a-customer-via-API/qaq-p/1450492#M57375) but only got one response;

> The reason is because The organization concept in Jira ServiceDesk is a global entity rather than a project level entity . (Customers ultimately are  linked to Jira ServiceDesk Organization(s) )

Perhaps I'm being thick here, but I do not understand that answer. I do appreciate that a customer is a global object, but why would an agent account have permission to create a global object, but also *not* have permission to create a global object?

I therefore have two questions

1. Am I doing it correctly or am I missing something? Is there a "best" way to create a customer?
2. If I am doing it correctly, what is the reason for this disparity?

Thanks!

James

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible unless you have global admin rights. Atlassian have logged [JSDCLOUD-9396](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JSDCLOUD-9396).